# How to do parital update for complex object structure in cosmos Db

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a complex json structure

```json
    {
        "id": "378a1f20-300a-49af-85a4-925d6abf2fc1",
        "ConsumerID": "1234",
        "ConsumerName": "VenkattrajanCoMOS",
        "OtherNames": [
            "Subramaniyam"
        ],
        "Addresses": {
            "StreetAddress1": "chennaiUpdate",
            "StreetAddress2": "anna nagar",
            "AptSuiteBldg": "test",
            "City": "chennai",
            "State": "tamilnadu",
            "Zip": "60039",
            "GeoCode": "test",
            "CertificateOfInsurance": 0,
            "AddressNotes": "TEst address",
            "GateCode": "789",
            "AverageTimeToLoadAndUnload": 0,
            "AddressVerified": 0
        },
        "Contact": [
            {
                "Type": "phone",
                "Value": "9952026876",
                "Textable": 0,
                "OptInSmsStatus": "yes",
                "OptInSmsTimestamp": "testtimestamp",
                "OptInStatus": "no",
                "OptInStatusTimestamp": "testtimestamp",
                "MessageId": "testmessageid"
            }
        ],
        "History": [
            {
                "EventId": "1",
                "EventDescription": "Customer inserted",
                "EventTimeStamp": "testTimeStamp",
                "EventUser": "testeventuser"
            }
        ],
        "Retailers": [
            {
                "RetailerCode": "OTH"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am using currently using ReplaceItemAsync in my c# code

```cs
public async Task UpdateCustomerProfileAsyncDAL(string id, CustomerProfile customerProfile)
{
   try
   {
      _logger.LogInformation($"CustomerProfileDAL UpdateCustomerProfileAsyncDAL started. customerId {customerProfile.ConsumerID} and identity {id}");
      await _container.ReplaceItemAsync<CustomerProfile>(customerProfile, id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       _logger.LogError($"Error in method CustomerProfileDAL UpdateCustomerProfileAsyncDAL for customerId  : {customerProfile.ConsumerID} and identity {id}, Error: {ex.Message}-{ex.InnerException}-{ex.StackTrace}");
       throw;
    }
}
```

I will be updating any of the field in the json document it seems like in need to construct patchOperations. if i use PatchItemAsync Note :- update can be for any field

Comment: which array you want to update? post the expected output

Comment: In a partial update, you always have to specify the path to the property that you want to update. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update-getting-started?tabs=dotnet%2Cpython). There is no magic that allows you to patch any field.